# Wrong function result from setInterval

Tags: javascript

When I run the countdown function inside setIntervals it returns same output every second but the value that I passing to the function changes. Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wre8zgat/)

```
var date = new Date(2017, 3, 27, 21).getTime();
function countdown(milliseconds) {
    console.log(milliseconds);
    var CDDate = {
        seconds: 0,
        minutes: 0,
        hours: 0,
        days: 0
    }
    x = milliseconds / 1000;
    CDDate.seconds = Math.round(x % 60);
    x /= 60;
    CDDate.minutes = Math.round(x % 60);
    x /= 60;
    CDDate.hours = Math.round(x % 25);
    x /= 24;
    CDDate.days = Math.floor(x);
    return CDDate;
}

var diff = date - Date.now();
setInterval(function(){
    console.log(countdown(--diff));
},1000)
```

Comment: You're counting down one millisecond every second, it takes a few hours before you see any change in the seconds and minutes

Comment: @adeneo oh stupid me :/ yeah stupid question

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/wre8zgat/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working example code:

```js
var date = new Date(2017, 3, 27, 21).getTime();
function countdown(milliseconds) {
    var CDDate = {
        seconds: 0,
        minutes: 0,
        hours: 0,
        days: 0
    }
    x = milliseconds;
    CDDate.seconds = Math.round((x+30) % 60);
    x = (x/60);
    CDDate.minutes = Math.round(x % 60);
    x = x/60;
    CDDate.hours = Math.round(x % 24);
    x = x/24;
    CDDate.days = Math.floor(x);
    return CDDate;
}
var diff = date - Date.now();
diff = diff/1000;
setInterval(function(){
    var returnVal = countdown(--diff);
    document.getElementById('low').innerHTML = returnVal.seconds;
    document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = returnVal.minutes;
    document.getElementById('hrs').innerHTML = returnVal.hours;
    document.getElementById('day').innerHTML = returnVal.days;
},1000)
```

```html
Seconds: <div id="low"></div>
Minuts: <div id="min"></div>
Hours: <div id="hrs"></div>
Days: <div id="day"></div>
<div id="mil"></div>
```

You were counting the millisecond as second and in the setInterval function you have passed the 1 sec. time to recall the function.

I have added this line: `diff = diff/1000;` after diff calculation and convert it into second. Now it is working fine.